# What does Symfony cache:clear actually do?

Tags: php, symfony

I have bee using Symfony for a while now, and recently ran into an issue where the app/console cache:clear  didn't want to clear the cache.

I then discovered that you can manually remove the app/cache directory to clear the cache.

So aside from doing the app/cache folder, what does cache:clear actually do? Why would i keep using it rather than removing the cache folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also does the cache warmup (at least in version 3.1, which I'm currently using) unless you tell it not to do so with `--no-warmup`.

It's also easier and faster to run commands in IDEs like PHPStorm then manually doing things such as removing files.

Basically you can just remove cache directory if you prefer such way. Cache warmup will be performed at first Symfony request is needed.

Comment: Btw to detail on what cache warmup does as that term doesn't tell you much unless you know what you are talking about. It just generates all the caching files as like when a user would visit it the first time. If you _do not do this_, the first user to visit will get a massive delay as he has to wait for all cache files to generate. [kernel cache warmer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-cache-warmer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach event to clear some of your custom cache. 
This mean if you remove cache directory, you're not sure to clear custom cache handling